# double.IsNan is not defined? (upgrade from 1.9.7.8 -> 2.0)

Tags: .net-3.5, f#

Trying out VS 2010, but still want to target .NET 3.5.  Have all my C# projects set with:

```
<PropertyGroup> <LangVersion>3</LangVersion> </PropertyGroup>
```

And seems to be working fine.  The F# is acting funny though.. I can't use the double.IsNaN method.

```
let foo = double.IsNaN(bar)


The field, constructor, or member 'IsNaN' is not defined.
```

Similarly, String.Format is broke too:

```
The field, constructor, or member 'Format' is not defined.
```

I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly stated "open System" and capitalized double (Double).

Not sure why it was fine before..

Comment: I think that at some point `double` was added as a type conversion operator, which takes priority over the type alias for `System.Double`.